# Traveling from Netherlands to USA through Curacao

Tags: air-travel, schengen, international-travel, esta

My girlfriend is planning to travel to Curacao from the Netherlands early in September hoping that flights to USA open back up (*any expectation on whether it will?*). She is a Dutch citizen planning to travel on an ESTA (visa waiver) after quarantining for 14 days in Curacao into the USA. Will this be alright or are CBP antsy about letting this happen? Any stories about people trying this through other countries at the moment?

Comment: This should be fine providing things stay as they are but as we have seen in New Zealand this week, things can change very rapidly. We're not offering any guesses on what might be happening in September.

Comment: And the UK 'closing' for several EU countries, some of them with very little advance warning.

Comment: Yea and there's no confirmation yet about Curacao opening up flights to the USA, considering Turkey now.